# how to get HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse in undertow?

Tags: undertow

I used undertow to develop a web, but I don't know how to get HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in the route. I don't want to use the HttpServerExchange object.

I tried to use

```java
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) exchange.getAttachment(ServletRequestContext.ATTACHMENT_KEY).getServletRequest();
```

to get the request, but it failed.

```java
public class HelloServer {

  private static HttpHandler handler = new RoutingHandler()
      .get("/", HelloServer::doGet);

  private static void doGet(HttpServerExchange exchange) {
    ServletRequestContext attachment = exchange.getAttachment(ServletRequestContext.ATTACHMENT_KEY);
    System.out.println(attachment); // attachment: null
    exchange.getResponseSender().send("hello world");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Undertow undertow = Undertow.builder()
        .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
        .setHandler(handler)
        .build();
    undertow.start();
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ServletRequestContext.current().getServletRequest()
```